# It is better to have more B-frames or more P-frame for video streaming?

Tags: streaming, h.264, handbrake, bitrate

I'm trying to re-encode (H.264) some videos from my movie library in order to put them on a NAS and stream them to a smartTV through WiFi.

In order to do so, I'm using *HandBrake* on MacOS and – among my experiments – I noticed that it promotes more B-frames.

If I have understood correctly, those B-frames needs more CPU time and a larger buffer in memory in order to be properly elaborated and I'm not sure if a device such as a general smartTV (of few years) can take advantage of that (with 1080p sources, I used the 4.1 high profile).

Here is an example plotted from *FFprobe* on the same video source (1080p) before and after re-encoding (and a little filter to reduce noise) at the target bitrate (2-pass VBR):
[image: Before]
[image: After]

What do you think or suggest ?

I ask because the resulting file size is very similar and I can't really notice a difference (apart from the noisier frames).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Q: Is it **better** to have more B-frames or more P-frame for video streaming?".

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types

> The three major picture types used in the different video algorithms are I, P and B. They are different in the following characteristics:
>
> I‑frames are the least compressible but don't require other video frames to decode.
>
> P‑frames can use data from previous frames to decompress and are more compressible than I‑frames.
>
> B‑frames can use both previous and forward frames for data reference to get the highest amount of data compression.

So for the sake of **better** compression and equal quality: B Frames are better.

In *your* case **better** means that your TV better be able to decode and properly play your videos after spending hours/days transcoding them.

So try one video using B-Frames, if there are glitches or you can't rewind properly use P-Frames. Be careful using a large number of B-Frames as that will use more Buffer.

The "CPU time" you refer to applies on your computer, for the TV's Hardware decoding ASIC it shouldn't be a problem. As for Memory the reverse is true, your computer will have enough memory for many B-Frames but your TV might only have enough memory for a few.

Blu-Ray uses 3 B-Frames so your TV ought to accept that many.